# Can not add ManyToManyFields using froms.py in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, many-to-many

I am trying to add data in a model using django forms but getting

***Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use tag.set() instead.***
Please help me solve this. I am using multiselect field to send data to views.py.

***models.py***

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tags'

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feature_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/', verbose_name='Add Feature Image')
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, related_name='post_tags', verbose_name='Add Tags')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

***forms.py***

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = [...]
```

***views***

```
def adminNewPostView(request):
    form = forms.PostForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        tags = request.POST.getlist('tagName')
        form = forms.PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.category = cat
            if subcat:
                post.sub_categories = subcat
            if subfil:
                post.filter_option = subfil

            add_tags = models.Tags.objects.filter(tag__in=tags)

            for tl in add_tags:
                post.tag = tl # Getting Error here

            post.save()

         
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_app:index'))
```

***Error***

***Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use tag.set() instead.***

Comment: Does your form contains a field for the many-to-many field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py

```
def adminNewPostView(request):
    form = forms.PostForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        tags = request.POST.getlist('tagName')
        form = forms.PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.category = cat
            if subcat:
                post.sub_categories = subcat
            if subfil:
                post.filter_option = subfil

            post.save()
            add_tags = models.Tags.objects.filter(tag__in=tags)

            for tl in add_tags:
                post.tag.add(tl) # new
         
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_app:index'))
```

to learn more about this please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/ 
or here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships
there is also an other way of doing it.like this

```
def adminNewPostView(request):
    form = forms.PostForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        tags = request.POST.getlist('tagName')
        form = forms.PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.category = cat
            if subcat:
                post.sub_categories = subcat
            if subfil:
                post.filter_option = subfil
            post.save()
            add_tags = models.Tags.objects.filter(tag__in=tags)

            post.tag.add(*add_tags) # new

            

         
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_app:index'))
```

Comment: Tried this, but getting `"<Post: Test Blog>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: @NahidujjamanHridoy i edited my answer.you should call post.save() before the add_tags variable.try it and let me know if it works.first you need to save the post and after you can add the tag.

Comment: @NahidujjamanHridoy and also make sure to put blank=True and null=True to the model Post in the tag field.after that run migrations and migrate it should work.because if you use post.save() without a tag it will raise an error because from what i see you tag is required.

Answer (score 0):

A Django form can handle `ManyToManyField`s itself, but can only do that with `.save_m2m()` or `.save()` *without* using `commit=False`: first it needs to save the `Post` object since it needs the primary key of that `Post` object to link the object to other items.

If your `PostForm` uses the `tag` field:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    …
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        #          ↓ tag field
        fields = ['tag', 'other', 'fields']
```

then we can let the form do the work for us:

from django.shortcuts import redirect

```
def adminNewPostView(request):
    form = forms.PostForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        …
        tags = request.POST.getlist('tagName')
        form = forms.PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            if subcat:
                form.instance.sub_categories = subcat
            if subfil:
                form.instance.filter_option = subfil
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.instance.category = cat
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog_app:index')
```

Comment: No. My `PostForm` doesn't have `tag` field. I am sending that from html using `select2` `multiselect` field.

Comment: @NahidujjamanHridoy: you can work with `select2` widgets in Django: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/